# Customzing Eventbrite list, I get unexpected T_FUNCTION, but it works locally

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error, eventbrite

I'm displaying an events list from my Eventbrite account and when run locally, it works. When I upload it to my live test site, it triggers:

**Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in ... on line ...

My PHP is as follows and pretty much verbatim from https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/blob/master/examples/event-list-example.md

```
<?php
include "Eventbrite.php";
$authentication_tokens = array('app_key'  => 'XXXXXXXX',
                           'user_key' => '123456789');
$eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens );

$events = $eb_client->user_list_events();

$custom_render_function = function($evnt){
$time = strtotime($evnt->start_date);
    if( isset($evnt->venue) && isset( $evnt->venue->name )){ 
        $venue_name = $evnt->venue->name;
    }else{
        $venue_name = 'online';
    }   
$event_html = "<div class='eb_event_list_item' id='evnt_div_" . $evnt->id ."'>
                    <span class='eb_event_list_date'>" . strftime('%a, %B %e', $time) . "</span>
                    <a class='eb_event_list_title' href='" . $evnt->url."'>".$evnt->title."</a>
                    <span class='eb_event_list_time'>" . strftime('%l:%M %P', $time) . "</span>
                    <span class='eb_event_list_location'>" . $venue_name . "</span>
                </div>\n";
return $event_html;
}

?>

<?= $event_list_html = Eventbrite::eventList( $events, $custom_render_function); ?>
```

Can anyone help me see where I've gone wrong?

**UPDATE:**
It was the version of PHP on the server (5.3). Mine had to be updated by the hosting service but it took only 30secs and this issue was resolved.

Comment: I think its because of short `php tag <?`

Comment: @Akam What do you suggest I change that too? It's like that in the example but I have tried `<?php=`, `<?php =` and `<?php` with no success.

Comment: @glenn: `<?php phpinfo();` in a PHP-file of it's own, request it, check the PHP version. Everything below PHP 5.4 is end of life. Upgrade. And delete the new file again after you've used it.